# Rename first row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

Update:

[View of the Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6atC.png)

### @jezrael, please find the image of the Dataframe that I am referring to. Hope this helps.

I have a pandas dataframe built using (value_counts) function. The output has a header of two columns with labels Unnamed:0,Unnamed:1

Given below is the view of the Dataframe:

```
Unnamed:0,Unnammed:1
Drop less than 1%,3
Drop less than 2%,5
Drop less than 3%,2
```

Given below is the code I have used to build this Dataframe:

```
Output1.groupby(['Status']).agg(lambda x: x.mad())
Output1 = Output1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
SumMail = pd.DataFrame(pd.value_counts(Output1['Status']).sort_index())
SumMail.rename(columns=lambda x: x[10:], inplace=True)
```

Could anyone advice, how I could have this headers have a label. Thanks.

Thanks..

Comment: `df.columns = ['a','b']` should working.

Comment: What is your input sample data?

Comment: @jezrael, given below is the view of the Output1 Dataframe


,,Status
0,ABC,Drop less than 1%
1,DEF,Drop less than 1%
2, KLM,Drop less than 2%
3,XYZ,Drop less than 3%

Comment: Can you check answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need:

```
Output1 = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ['Drop less than 1%',
                                   'Drop less than 1%',
                                    np.nan, 
                                   'Drop less than 2%', 
                                   'Drop less than 2%', 
                                   'Drop less than 3%']})

print (Output1)
              Status
0  Drop less than 1%
1  Drop less than 1%
2                NaN
3  Drop less than 2%
4  Drop less than 2%
5  Drop less than 3%

Output1 = Output1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
SumMail = (Output1['Status'].value_counts()
                            .sort_index()
                            .head(10)
                            .rename_axis('a')
                            .reset_index(name='b'))
print (SumMail)
                   a  b
0                     1
1  Drop less than 1%  2
2  Drop less than 2%  2
3  Drop less than 3%  1
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks a lot this worked perfectly fine as per what I was looking for. However the Dataframe extracted has the below structure

,Unnamed:0,a,b
0,0,Drop less than 1%, 1
1,1,Drop less than 2%,2
2,2,Drop less than 3%,2

Could you please help remove this column labelled Unnamed:0

I tried the below function to remove this column

SumMail.drop(SumMail.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)

It removed the Status column and not the Unnamed:0 column.

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    8 non-null object
b    8 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
None

Comment: OK, so try `df = df.rename_axis(None)` or `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: and if also need create default index use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: tried all three options but the unnamed:0 column still shows up in the Dataframe ..

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: This returns just two columns as below:

['a', 'b']

But when I save the Dataframe and use it in the mail I see this extra column..

Comment: @Taukheer - So I have no idea, I think if use my code there should be all OK. Or there are 2 different DataFrames?

Comment: I have one Dataframe but create two csv files using this. One that has the complete raw data and the other that summarises by different categories. Thanks anyways for helping get the column labelled that was more important that this additional unnamed column

Comment: @Taukheer so now is no problem with unamed column?

Comment: Its still part of the extraction since you said you had no other idea I wanted to thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Taukheer - I have idea - Can you check `print (df.index.name)`, `print (df.columns.name)`, `print (df.columns.tolist())` and `print (df.index)` for  problematic DataFrame?

Comment: I ran the codes for both the Dataframes. Attached is the output for the first Dataframe. Shall add the output for the second Dataframe in the next comment due to space constraint..

I ran the 4 codes for both the Dataframes and they returned as below:
print (SumMail.index.name) -- None
print (SumMail.columns.name) -- None
print (SumMail.columns.tolist()) -- ['a','b']
print (SumMail.index) -- RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)

Comment: Output for the second Dataframe...


print (Output1.index.name) -- None
print (Output1.columns.name) -- None
print (Output1.columns.tolist()) -- ['Status']
print (Output1.index) -- Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...   281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290],
           dtype='int64', length=291)


Hope this helps

Comment: @Taukheer so all working nice? Can you add output of dataframe or csv where is `Unnamed:0`. Maybe we dont understand well each other. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my first message with view of the Dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael to fixing this.

Used the below to remove the unnamed:0 column

df = pd.read_csv('DF_csv.csv', index_col=[0])